# CSV to XML conversion Java

Tags: java, xml, csv

I was working on converting CSV to XML data. By looking at various examples I was able to write the code for parsing the CSV file and getting the XML file. However, the code I have written returns the XML file with incorrect tags.

This is the Code for Conversion:

```
    package com.adarsh.parse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;



public class Converter {

    /* Protected members to avoid instantiation */
    protected DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = null;
    protected DocumentBuilder domBuilder = null;
    /* Constant strings */
    // Input CSV file
    final String INPUT_FILE = "sample_data.csv";
    // Output XML document
    final String OUTPUT_FILE ="in.xml";
    // First element in the XML document
    final String FIRST_ELEMENT="school";
    public Converter(){
        try {
            domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            /* Obtaining instance of class DocumentBuilder */
            domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        }
        catch(ParserConfigurationException exp) {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());

        }
        catch(FactoryConfigurationError exp){
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception exp){
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
    }
    /**
     * This method converts the given CSV file into an XML document
     */
    public  int convert(String csvFileName, String xmlFileName) {
        int rowCount = -1;
        try {
            /* Initializing the XML document  */
            Document newDoc = domBuilder.newDocument();
            /* Creating the root element in the XML */
            Element rootElem = newDoc.createElement(FIRST_ELEMENT);
            newDoc.appendChild(rootElem);
            /* Reading the CSV file */
            BufferedReader csvFileReader;
            csvFileName = INPUT_FILE;
            csvFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileName));
            /* Initialize the number of fields to 0 */
            int fieldCount = 0;
            String[] csvFields = null;
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = null;

            /**
             * Map the column names in the CSV file as the elements in the XML
             * document, eliminate any other characters not eligible for XML element
             * naming
             */
            /* Initialize the current line variable */
            String currLine = csvFileReader.readLine();
            /* Loop until we reach the end of the file 
             * edge case: Empty CSV file
             * */

            if(currLine != null) {
                /* Separate fields based on commas */
                stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currLine, ",");
                fieldCount = stringTokenizer.countTokens();
                /* If there is data in the CSV file */
                if(fieldCount > 0) {
                    /* Initialize a String Array of Fields */
                    csvFields = new String[fieldCount];
                    int i = 0;
                    /* Loop till all elements are found and save fields */
                    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                        csvFields[i++] = String.valueOf(stringTokenizer.nextElement());
                    }
                }

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Nothing to parse");
            }
            /* reading rows from the CSV file */
            while((currLine = csvFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currLine, ",");
                fieldCount = stringTokenizer.countTokens();
                /* if rows exist in the CSV file*/
                if(fieldCount > 0) {
                    /* Create the row element*/
                    Element rowElem = newDoc.createElement("row");
                    int i = 0;
                    /* until there are more elements*/
                    while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                        try {
                            /* Append each element found to each row element*/
                            String currValue = String.valueOf(stringTokenizer.nextElement());
                            Element currElem = newDoc.createElement(csvFields[i++]);
                            currElem.appendChild(newDoc.createTextNode(currValue));
                            rowElem.appendChild(currElem);
                        }
                        catch(Exception exp) {

                        }
                    }
                    /* Append the rows to the root element*/
                    rootElem.appendChild(rowElem);
                    rowCount++;
                }
            }
            /* Finish reading the CSV file */
            csvFileReader.close();

            /* Saving the generated XML doc into required format file to disk */
            TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
            Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer(); 
            aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            aTransformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            Source src = new DOMSource(newDoc);
            xmlFileName = OUTPUT_FILE;
            Result dest = new StreamResult(new File(xmlFileName)); 
            aTransformer.transform(src, dest); 

            rowCount++;
        }
        catch(IOException exp) {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception exp) {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
        /* Number of rows parsed into XML */
        return rowCount;

    }

}
```

This is the sample CSV data in the file:

> classroom_id,classroom_name,teacher_1_id,teacher_1_last_name,teacher_1_first_name,teacher_2_id,teacher_2_last_name,teacher_2_first_name,student_id,student_last_name,student_first_name,student_grade
>   103, Brian's Homeroom, 10300000001, O'Donnell, Brian, , , , , , , 102,
>   Mr. Smith's PhysEd Class, 10200000001, Smith, Arthur, 10200000011,
>   Patterson, John, 10200000011, McCrancy, Brandon, 1 102, Mr. Smith's
>   PhysEd Class, 10200000001, Smith, Arthur, 10200000011, Patterson,
>   John, 10200000018, Reginald, Alexis, 1 102, Mr. Smith's PhysEd Class,
>   10200000001, Smith, Arthur, 10200000011, Patterson, John, 10200000019,
>   Gayle, Matthew, 1 102, Mr. Smith's PhysEd Class, 10200000001, Smith,
>   Arthur, 10200000011, Patterson, John, 10200000010, Smith, Nathaniel, 1
>   102, Mr. Smith's PhysEd Class, 10200000001, Smith, Arthur,
>   10200000011, Patterson, John, 10200000013, Lanni, Erica, 1 102, Mr.
>   Smith's PhysEd Class, 10200000001, Smith, Arthur, 10200000011,
>   Patterson, John, 10200000014, Flores, Michael, 1 102, Mr. Smith's
>   PhysEd Class, 10200000001, Smith, Arthur, 10200000011, Patterson,
>   John, 10200000012, Marco, Elizabeth, 1 102, Mr. Smith's PhysEd Class,
>   10200000001, Smith, Arthur, 10200000011, Patterson, John, 10200000016,
>   Perez, Brittany, 1 102, Mr. Smith's PhysEd Class, 10200000001, Smith,
>   Arthur, 10200000011, Patterson, John, 10200000015, Hill, Jasmin, 1
>   102, Mr. Smith's PhysEd Class, 10200000001, Smith, Arthur,
>   10200000011, Patterson, John, 10200000017, Hiram, William, 1 101, Mrs.
>   Jones' Math Class, 10100000001, Jones, Barbara, , , , 10100000015,
>   Cruz, Alex, 1 101, Mrs. Jones' Math Class, 10100000001, Jones,
>   Barbara, , , , 10100000014, Garcia, Lizzie, 1 101, Mrs. Jones' Math
>   Class, 10100000001, Jones, Barbara, , , , 10100000013, Mercado, Toby,
>   1 101, Mrs. Jones' Math Class, 10100000001, Jones, Barbara, , , ,
>   10100000011, Gutierrez, Kimberly, 2 101, Mrs. Jones' Math Class,
>   10100000001, Jones, Barbara, , , , 10100000010, Gil, Michael, 2

I was expecting to get the output as following in XML file:

```
<grade id="1">
    <classroom id="101" name="Mrs. Jones' Math Class">
        <teacher id="10100000001" first_name="Barbara" last_name="Jones"/>

        <student id="10100000010" first_name="Michael" last_name="Gil"/>
        <student id="10100000011" first_name="Kimberly" last_name="Gutierrez"/>
        <student id="10100000013" first_name="Toby" last_name="Mercado"/>
        <student id="10100000014" first_name="Lizzie" last_name="Garcia"/>
        <student id="10100000015" first_name="Alex" last_name="Cruz"/>
    </classroom>


    <classroom id="102" name="Mr. Smith's PhysEd Class">
        <teacher id="10200000001" first_name="Arthur" last_name="Smith"/>
        <teacher id="10200000011" first_name="John" last_name="Patterson"/>

        <student id="10200000010" first_name="Nathaniel" last_name="Smith"/>
        <student id="10200000011" first_name="Brandon" last_name="McCrancy"/>
        <student id="10200000012" first_name="Elizabeth" last_name="Marco"/>
        <student id="10200000013" first_name="Erica" last_name="Lanni"/>
        <student id="10200000014" first_name="Michael" last_name="Flores"/>
        <student id="10200000015" first_name="Jasmin" last_name="Hill"/>
        <student id="10200000016" first_name="Brittany" last_name="Perez"/>
        <student id="10200000017" first_name="William" last_name="Hiram"/>
        <student id="10200000018" first_name="Alexis" last_name="Reginald"/>
        <student id="10200000019" first_name="Matthew" last_name="Gayle"/>
    </classroom>

    <classroom id="103" name="Brian's Homeroom">
        <teacher id="10300000001" first_name="Brian" last_name="O'Donnell"/>
    </classroom>
</grade>
```

This is how I am currently getting the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<school>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>101</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>101</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>101</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>101</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>101</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>102</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>102</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>102</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>102</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>102</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>102</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>102</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>102</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>102</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>102</classroom_id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <classroom_id>103</classroom_id>
    </row>
</school>
```

So could someone please help me with this? I was wondering where I am going wrong. Thanks

P.S. I have already referred to other question regarding CSV to XML conversions here on stackoverflow. However, I wasn't able to find a suitable solution or explanation to the problem which is specific to me.

P.S.S. Please don't suggest me to use XSLT if it isn't compulsory to parse such CSV data to XML. If there is no other choice then I would have to go learn XSLT as I have very little knowledge about XSLT. would appreciate it a lot if you would suggest changes in the code I have already written.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your CSV content have no newline separators.